# How to get the previous page url after redirect

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect, asp-classic, web-config

I have old asp classic project, which has redirect rule in web.config, so when user comes from old browsers he is redirected to some page. But in this page should be a button like "No, i want to use old browser", that should redirect person to page he was previously.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to know the previous URL when there is redirect and no link to that page (HTTP_Referrer isn't working).

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Please be more precise on what you mean by "HTTP_Referrer is not working". What else have you tried? Can you provide some code?

Comment: I tried 
<a href="<%=Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()%>" id="returnToOld"><span>No, thank you</span></a>
And
<a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER").ToString()%>" id="returnToOld"><span>No, thank you</span></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using javascript:

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```

Or

```
window.history.back()
```

Comment: Great, <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)"> helped! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can request the HTTP host:

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
```

The browsers user agent isn't required to set the `HTTP_REFERRER` but host header has been required since HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it redirects to about:blank